# Seeing with sound software

Tags: android, windows

Does anyone know whether Google Glasses are compatible with vOICe technology?  http://www.seeingwithsound.com.  An aged aunt, who is almost totally blind, heard about this on the radio.  She would like to try it but is too old, frail and unused to technology to set this up or to contemplate walking around with a computer connected to a webcam.  If it were possible to load the application into a Google Glass that would be ideal but I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to [The vOICe for Android page](http://www.seeingwithsound.com/android.htm) on that website you linked, it gives information about using vOICe with Google Glass. They list a caveat however:

> Please note that the CPU of Google Glass is very slow by today's smartphone standards, such that The vOICe for Android wil appear very sluggish or even unresponsive on Google Glass.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so according to the android page on that website:
http://www.seeingwithsound.com/android.htm

However:
The CPU inbuilt into glass is apparently sluggish and may not be quick enough for her to use it accurately.

> Please note that the CPU of Google Glass is very slow by today's smartphone standards, such that The vOICe for Android wil appear very sluggish or even unresponsive on Google Glass. In fact, the Explorer Edition of Google Glass is not really powerful enough yet to deliver a good experience with The vOICe for Android, and future generations of Glass, or its competitors, will hopefully offer
> better performance

If you want to continue:

There is a section labelled:

> Running The vOICe for Android on Google Glass

This does require use of android SDK tools to install and launch and a larger battery is required.

> From a DOS shell on the PC, within the folder where you saved [vOICeAndroid.apk](http://www.seeingwithsound.com/phone/vOICeAndroid.apk) apply the command
>
> adb install vOICeAndroid.apk to install The vOICe for Android, followed by    adb shell am start -n vOICe.vOICe/.The_vOICe
>
> to launch The vOICe for Android on Glass (and use "adb shell am force-stop vOICe.vOICe" to stop The vOICe). The Glass screen must be on when launching The vOICe, so you may need to tap the touchpad a few times during the launch to avoid the 10 second screen timeout of Glass
>
> If all went well, you should also be able to launch The vOICe for Android while not connected to a PC by saying "OK Glass - start imaging - The vOICe for Android".